# Angular 2: Datatable/HTML table - No data displayed on second time request

Tags: angular, angular-datatables

I'm facing an issue displaying data in an Angular Datatable or HTML table (tried both) when requesting data for the **second** time or subsequent attempts

First time loading happens appropriately, but if I navigate to another page and then come back, I see blank/no data in the tables. However, JSON data is fetched and displayed in console correctly. Also, if I interpolate the data directly in a div, JSON is again displayed without any issue. But the same isn't working with tables.

This is the snippet I have used :

**Component**
getDrugs.component.ts

```
ngOnInit()
{              
    this.adminService.getAllDrugs().subscribe(
       res => {
           this.data = res;
           console.log(JSON.stringify(res));          
           //return res;
       },
       err => {
           console.log("Error while retrieving existing Drug Details : " + err);
       }
   )
}
```

**Service**
drugs.service.ts

```
getAllDrugs(): any {
    console.log('getAllDrugs service invoked');

    return this.http.get(`${this.webApiBaseUrl}/GetDrugList`)
        .map(res => {                               
            console.log(res.json());
            return res.json();
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
            return Observable.throw(error);
        });                
}
```

**HTML Template**
getDrugs.html

```html
<form>              
    <ba-card title="Drug Records">      
                 
        <div class="form-group" *ngIf="data">                        
            <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" [mfData]="data" #mf="mfDataTable" [mfRowsOnPage]="rowsOnPage">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th style="width: 50%; font-weight:bold; font-size:larger; text-align:left;">
                            <mfDefaultSorter by="tradeName">Trade Name</mfDefaultSorter>
                        </th>
                        <th style="width: 50%; font-weight:bold; font-size:larger;">
                            <mfDefaultSorter by="comp">Composition</mfDefaultSorter>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr *ngFor="let item of mf.data; let i = index">
                        <td style="width: 50%; text-align:left;">{{item?.tradeName}}</td>           
                        <td style="width: 50%;">
                            <table  *ngIf = "item.composition">
                                <tr *ngFor="let comp of item.composition">
                                    {{comp}}
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="4">
                            <mfBootstrapPaginator [rowsOnPageSet]="[5,10,25]"></mfBootstrapPaginator>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
        </div>
    </ba-card>
</form>
```

Comment: You are subscribing an observable in ngOnInit method, when you make a new request you'll have another observable, but the reference in ngOnInit will still contain the previous one

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to put service to constructor not to ngOninit() ? 
In addition why did you use item?.composition as a syntax because you also checked that  *ngIf = "item.composition"

In normal table usage  then  then  is used.

Comment: Use above `<table>` tag as `<pre>{{item.composition}}</pre>` to check whether it exists or not....

Comment: Yes I have tried using the service in the constructor as well. But facing the same issue.